# How to change a jquery function variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How do I change a variable in a jQuery function?
Do I have to override the entire function?
Below is a function found in jquery.dataTable.js
How do I add a "," to the sValidChars variable.

```
    $.extend(DataTable.ext.aTypes, [
    function (sData) {
    ....
        var sValidChars = "0123456789.";
        ....
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried `var sValidChars = "0123456789.,";`? Could you provide a bit more context to what you're doing?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Do you want the caller to redefine all valid chars? Or just add/remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to override the entire function/change the code in the actual file.

It is because `sValidChars` is a local variable to the anonymous function, so it cannot be accessed outside the function scope.